Prove that $n$ is a time-constructible function
I am reading Arora and Barak's book: "Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach". On page 16, the authors wrote:

A function $T: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is time constructible if $T(n) \geq n$ and there is a TM $M$ that computes the function $x \mapsto \llcorner T(|x|) \lrcorner$ in time $T(n)$. (As usual, $\llcorner T(|x|) \lrcorner$ denotes the binary representation of the number $T(|x|)$.) Examples for time-constructible functions are $n$, $n \log n$, $n^2$, $2^n$.

I want to prove that $n$ is a time-constructible function, but I don't know how to begin. Any comments and answers are welcome.
Note: The length of a string $x$ is denoted by $|x|$.
Note 2: A similar question Example Turing Machine for a time-constructible function asked, "Shouldn't the definition make use of asymptotic notation?" The answer explains that it should be perfectly legal to use asymptotic notation here, but it did not prove that $n$ is a time-constructible function. In the answer, the author wrote "With a multitape Turing Machine, I can think of a $(3n+\log(n))$-time machine which computes $T(n)=n$, so I think it makes more sense to use asymptotic notation." However, the author did not describe the Turing machine. In my opinion, a complete proof must contain two parts: First, describe a Turing machine $M$ that computes the function $x \mapsto \llcorner |x| \lrcorner$. To describe a Turing machine, one needs to define the alphabet $\Gamma$, the state set $Q$, and the transition function $\delta$. Second, prove that the time of the computation is $O(n)$.

I think the book is wrong here. For such small T(n) without asymptotic notation, the precise definition matters. The machine cannot even read the input without taking n+1 steps (instead of n steps) because the input tape contains the special "start" symbol. I found the same question

To @pcpthm: Thank you for your comment. I will see "the same question" you mentioned.

I think the linked question by pcpthm answers this. It should simply be $O(T(n))$ instead of $T(n)$, then the theorem holds.

This question is similar to: Example Turing Machine for a time-constructible function. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To @CalebStanford: Thank you for your comment. I will read the "linked question".

To @xskxzr: Thank you for your comment. I will read "Example Turing Machine for a time-constructible function".

You essentially need to describe a TM $T$ that given input $x$ computes the binary representation of $|x|$.  Note that a full proof does not require you to define every component of the machine formally -- after you get convinced that you can define a machine for basic operations like "binary addition" or "shifting the input" or "adding a special letter at the begging of the input", etc, then you can simply get convinced and also convince the reader that each part can be implemented, and give a high-level description of a machine that uses these small parts instead.
If you insist on getting a low-level implementation of what you are asking for, then you can simply search "Turing machine for converting unary to binary", and I am pretty sure you will find some directions online.
Here is a description of a machine $T$ that given input $x$ outputs $|x|$ in binary. The description is not too low-level, and not too high-level, but is intentionally made appropriate for those who just came across Turing machines.
Given input $x$, the machine $T$ operates as follows:
1- Write a special letter $\\\$$ at the leftmost tape cell, and move the input $x$ one cell to the right (at this point, you have $\\\$x$ written on the tape).
2- Write $\\\$ 0$ after $x$ (at this point, you have $\\\$x\\\$ 0$ written on the tape).
3- Move the head of $T$ to the right dollar.
4- As long as there are letters between the 2 $\\\$$'s, go (left to right) over the first non-crossed letter between the dollars, and cross it, that is, replace it with the special letter $\#$, and go back after the $\\\$$ dollar on the right to add 1 to the binary number written there.
Now you have that the tape's content is of the form $\\\$ \#\# \cdots \# \cdot \\\$ \lfloor{|x|}\rfloor$
5- Erase $\\\$ \#\# \cdots \# \cdot \\\$$, move $\lfloor{|x|}\rfloor$ to the left, and halt.
Let's analyze the runtime of $T$. Given a binary number with $b$ bits, it takes $O(b)$ time to add 1 to it. In our example, $b=log(|x|)$, so each time we add 1 to the binary number, it costs us $O(log(|x|))$. The problem is that searching for a letter to cross may involve scanning the tape for $O(|x|)$ cells, and going the way back $O(|x|)$ cells. Thus, each iteration takes $O(|x| + log |x|) = O(|x|)$ steps, so we have a total of $O(|x|^2)$ steps.
We can modify the above implementation as follows. Start similarly to what we did, but whenever we find an input letter left of the second  $\\\$$, instead of crossing it with $\#$, we
simply shift (one cell to the left) the binary number we have computed so far. Each such shift takes $O(log |x|)$
steps, so we get a total of O(|x| log |x|) steps.
Good, so we improved to $O(|x|log|x|)$, but as you see it is intuitively harder to improve the runtime further given the way binary numbers are presented.
To improve the runtime to $O(|x|)$, one trick is to change the representation of the binary number. One way to do it, is to represent the binary number from right to left instead of left to right. That is, we represent the number 2 in binary as $01$.
Now consider the function $t: \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ (t, for tail) that maps $n$ to the number of 1's at the end of $\lfloor{n}\rfloor$. In particular, $t(0) = 0, t(1)=1, t(2) = 0, t(3) = 2$, and $t(7)=3$.
Now the cost of "adding 1" (to the modified binary representation) $|x|$ times is $t(0)+t(1)+ \cdots + t(|x|)$, and one can show that it takes $O(|x|)$ time in total to compute $\lfloor{|x|}\rfloor$ as explained, for example, in the accepted answer here. Once you have computed the answer, you can reverse it to the standard binary representation, in linear time, using a 2-tape Turing machine.

To Bader Abu Radi: Thank you for posting your answer. I will read your answer and try to understand your answer.

@Wei-ChengLiu No problem. If needed, we can discuss it in chat.

What is chat and how can I use it?

To @Bader Abu Radi: I think $b$ should be $\lfloor \log_2(|x|) \rfloor+1$.

Yes, good catch -- note that asymptotically, it does not really matter. We can write $\theta(log(|x|))$. I have been invited once to a chat room on this site, but I am not sure how to do it myself.

What is $\theta$? I only learned $\Theta$ in Arora and Barak's book "Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach", but I don't know what does $\theta$ stand for.

It means what you probably think it means. A combination of big O and big Omega -- an exact bound. Did I use the wrong notation?

In Arora and Barak's book, the definition of $\Theta$ is as follows: We say that $f=\Theta(g)$ is $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f)$. I cannot find the definition of $\theta$ in Arora and Barak's book, so I cannot be sure if you are using the wrong notation.

I don't understand why the cost of "adding 1" (to the modified binary representation) $|x|$ times is $t(0)+t(1)+...+t(|x|)$. Could you please explain it to me? Thank you.

When you add 1 to a binary number whose value is $n$, you perform $t(n)$ steps (note that the sum may not be exact-- I care only about asymptotics, that is, how this expression grows as a function of $n$). The reason for that is simply what we need to do when we apply addition: if the least significant bit is 0, you flip it to 1, otherwise, you flip the $t(n)$ least significant bits, which are 1's, to 0's, and then flip the bit after them to 1.

OK, I understand. Thank you very much.
